# Nested jar: URI

Tags: java, uri

The format of the `jar:` URI scheme is simply defined to be `jar:<url>!/[<entry>]`.

Is it possible to "nest" two such URIs together and refer to a file inside an archive inside an archive this way? Something like:

```
jar:jar:http://example.com/!/archive!/file
```

This should designate `/file` inside an archive `jar:http://example.com/!/archive`, that is `/archive` found in a file provided by `http://example.com/`. However, `URL.openConnection` throws an exception:

> java.net.MalformedURLException: no !/ in spec

I also cannot replace `!` with `%21` since that makes the `jar:` URI invalid, and I am not aware of any escaping that could be performed. Is this somehow possible? Or, as a more generic question, is it possible to store a URI with `!/` inside `<url>` so that it is preserved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is stated in the source code `java.net.JarURLConnection` does not handle nested Jar URIs.

Your example `jar:jar:http://example.com/!/archive!/file`is parsed as entry `archive!/file` in the archive `jar:http://example.com/`. The latter is not a valid jar URI. You can not either escape the `!/` sequences, because the text after `jar:` and before `!/` must be a valid URI without any translation.

You can of course provide your own `URLConnection` implementation that supports nested Jar URIs.

Answer (score 0):

While the other answer is indeed correct in the case of `JarURLConnection`, the use of `jar:` and similar URIs is not restricted to it. Such is the case of the [Apache Commons VFS](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/filesystems.html):

> `jar:// arch-file-uri[! absolute-path]`
>
> Where `arch-file-uri` refers to a file of any supported type, including other zip files. Note: if you would like to use the ! as normal character it must be escaped using `%21`.

"Normal character" means usage of the character in path to the file inside the archive, not in the inner URI. This makes `jar:jar:http://example.com/!/archive!/file` valid, as it is the *last* occurence of `!` that should be used as a delimiter.

Note that the inner URI should probably still remain unescaped, thus it is impossible to use `#` there.